# How can I ensure to get libEGL V1.4 on Android it always reports V1.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I'm working on an WebGL plugin for Flutter where I have to use the EGL library from Dart and Java.

In Dart I load libegl.so dynamically and when I call `eglInitialize` I get V1.4 as result. Which also means the correct version is on the system.

When I call in my Java plugin

```java
      EGLDisplay display = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

      int[] version = new int[2];
      boolean initializeResult = EGL14.eglInitialize(display, version, 0, version, 1);
      if (!initializeResult) {
        result.error("EGL InitError", "eglInit failed", null);
        return;
      }

      Log.i("FlutterWegGL", "EGL version in native plugin " + version[0] + "." + version[1]);
```

I always get 1.0 but I need V1.4

I'm no Android native developer, so I probably missed something.
Do I have to set something in my build.gradle to get the correct library?

Comment: did you have this in your manifest.xml
```java
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Yes I did include that entry

Comment: are you using real device or emulator ?

Comment: On the emulator which I switched to Opengl ES 3.1 will later try on a real phone

Comment: it's better to work on real device but in emulator configuration did you force the emulator to use graphic card

Comment: Yep I did, I just tried with my Pixel 3a, same result.

Comment: I tried it on a real device with no difference

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced same symptom. This may be some kind of bug of Android OS.

The bug is just about the version info returned from the `EGL14.eglInitialize` method. This doesn't mean the device's true EGL version is `1.0`. It would be `1.4` or `1.5` on recent devices.

I found a workaround. Just use two discrete `IntArray`s to receive version info.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val eglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        if (eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw RuntimeException("unable to get EGL14 display")
        }

        val majorVersion = IntArray(1)
        val minorVersion = IntArray(1)
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, majorVersion, 0, minorVersion, 0)) {
            throw RuntimeException("unable to initialize EGL14")
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "EGL version: ${majorVersion[0]}.${minorVersion[0]}")
    }
}
```

result:

> 2022-02-14 21:57:27.684 9287-9287/com.stackoverflow D/TAG: EGL
> version: 1.5

I don't know why, but when you use a single `IntArray` with `offset` `0` and `1`, minor version won't be updated (for example, if you pre-set `array[1]` as `9`, it remains `9`). This should be a bug.

Comment: thanks a lot will check that. But I think I tried just to ignore the error and when trying to create a context with the GL3.0 I got an error when I tries it.

Comment: Had the same issue and this worked for me, I am correctly getting EGL 1.5. Tested on a Pixel 4.